# how to write a makefile in python?

Tags: python, makefile

I have 3 python codes, and they are completely separated codes (the results are not related to each other). I have to run these codes everyday and while using 1 laptop, I have to run them one by one.

How can I write a main code (sth like makefile), that by running that code, the codes will be run one by one?
I mean:
1) the first code run and then finish
2) the second code run and then finish
3) the third code run and then finish

While my codding is not good, that would be nice of you if you can help me in details.

Comment: You probably want a "shell script" or "batch file", depending on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand "write a Makefile in Python"

If you already know what a Makefile is, then just call your three Python scripts from it, and they will run in order

```
run:
    python a.py
    python b.py
    python c.py
```

Although, a plain shell script would work just as well

Comment: Thanks, I had been familiar with makefile in fortran. Not in python. So, I will make a file just like 1.py and the inside is what you wrote. There is no need to call any specific function (such as numpy or ...) correct?    thank you very much

Comment: the point is that I do not know how to write makefile in python!

Comment: What I wrote is a Makefile, not a Python script. You don't "write a Makefile in Python". You just write a Makefile... They're not specific to any particular programming language